# Django error python raise ImproperlyConfigured

Tags: python, django, syntax-error

raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting LOGGING_CONFIG, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

I added setting.configure() in every file

Comment: Hello, please provide more details about your project's setup, such as the directory structure and any relevant code snippets, so I can assist you further.

Comment: raise RuntimeError(
RuntimeError: Model class django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType doesn't declare an explicit app_label and isn't in an application in INSTALLED_APPS.
I also get this error

Comment: INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes.models.ContentType',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'core',
    'userprofile',
    'dashboard',
]

Comment: @F A edit your question to add the information. your settings.py file and the directory structure and how you are running the app.